# Struggle accessing array in json object - ANGULAR

Tags: json, angular, ionic5

i would like to access the values assigned to the property `opzioni` in this `json` i get from my `api`, but i have some issues doing it.

```
[
 { 
   "isActive": "yes",
   "_id": "60e04e583a5c9f0004ac1524",
   "titolo": "Test123",
   "sottotitolo": "bla bla bla bla",
   "descrizione": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
   "tipo": "pal",
   "opzioni": [
                {
                  "nome": "Name 1"
                },
                {
                  "nome": "Name 2"
                 },
                 {
                  "nome": "Name 3"
                 }
              ],
    "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: `data[0].opzioni`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the root object is an array. You can access specific attributes within an array using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, for example:

```
const data = [ { "isActive": "yes", "_id": "60e04e583a5c9f0004ac1524", "titolo": "Test123", "sottotitolo": "bla bla bla bla", "descrizione": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "tipo": "pal", "opzioni": [ { "nome": "Name 1" }, { "nome": "Name 2" }, { "nome": "Name 3" } ], "__v": 0 } ]

const opzioniArray = data.map(i => i.opzioni);
```

This will remap the array to be a list of all `opzioni` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now my problem is accessing that array, because now it gives me something like ->. 0:Array(3) 0:{nome: "name 1" } 1:{nome: "name 2" } 2:{nome: "name 3" } and the ngFor iterates just for one time. :/